# Series Expansion within a fraction

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I'm currently reading "The cumulant lattice Boltzmann equation in three dimensions: Theory and validation" from Geier et. al. and have some trouble in a proof.

We have given multivariat cumulants (normalized with $m_{00}$) in terms of moments, like the following:

$$
  K_{11} = m_{11} - \frac{m_{10}m_{01}}{m_{00}}
$$

We can expand $K$ for expansion parameter $\epsilon$ to get our series expansion
\begin{equation}
  K_{11} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \epsilon^i K_{11}^{(i)}
\end{equation}

If I now want to compute, let's say, $K_{11}^{(2)}$ in terms of expanded moments, I'd say we have to do

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    K_{11} & = m_{11} - \frac{m_{10}m_{01}}{m_{00}}\\
    \Leftrightarrow
    \sum_{i=0}^\infty \epsilon^i K_{11}^{(i)}
    & = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \epsilon^i m_{11}^{(i)} -
    \frac{\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty \epsilon^{i+j} m_{10}^{(i)}m_{01}^{(j)}}
         {\sum_{i=0}^\infty \epsilon^i m_{00}^{(i)}}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and match the $\epsilon$ coefficient on both sides.

In the paper, he states
\begin{equation}
  K_{11}^{(2)}
  = m_{11}^{(2)} -
  \frac{m_{10}^{(1)}m_{01}^{(1)}}
       {m_{00}^{(0)}}
\end{equation}
Which obviously has same $\epsilon$ coefficients on both sides, but I can't see, why this is the right way to do it?

**Edit**: thanks for pointing to the geometric series.

The sum in the denominater can be dealt with a geometric series, like follows
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    K_{11} & = m_{11} - \frac{m_{10}m_{01}}{m_{00}}\\
    \Leftrightarrow
    \sum_{i=0}^\infty \epsilon^i K_{11}^{(i)}
    & = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \epsilon^i m_{11}^{(i)} -
    \frac{\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty \epsilon^{i+j} m_{10}^{(i)}m_{01}^{(j)}}
        {\sum_{i=0}^\infty \epsilon^i m_{00}^{(i)}}\\
    \Leftrightarrow
    \sum_{i=0}^\infty \epsilon^i K_{11}^{(i)}
    & = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \epsilon^i m_{11}^{(i)} -
    \frac{\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty \epsilon^{i+j} m_{10}^{(i)}m_{01}^{(j)}}
        {m_{00}^{(0)}}
        \frac{1}{1 - \sum_{i=1}^\infty \epsilon^i \frac{ - m_{00}^{(i)}}{ m_{00}^{(0)}}}\\
    \Leftrightarrow
    \sum_{i=0}^\infty \epsilon^i K_{11}^{(i)}
    & = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \epsilon^i m_{11}^{(i)} -
    \frac{\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty \epsilon^{i+j} m_{10}^{(i)}m_{01}^{(j)}}
        {m_{00}^{(0)}}
    \sum_{j=0}^\infty {\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty \epsilon^i \frac{ - m_{00}^{(i)}}{ m_{00}^{(0)}}\right)}^j
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Which leaves the second order terms
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    K_{11}^{(2)}
    &= m_{11}^{(2)} \\
    &\quad-
    \frac{
      m_{10}^{(1)}m_{01}^{(1)}
    + m_{10}^{(0)}m_{01}^{(2)}
    + m_{10}^{(2)}m_{01}^{(0)}
    }{m_{00}^{(0)}}\underbrace{1}_{j=0}\\
    &\quad
    +(m_{10}^{(1)}m_{01}^{(0)} + m_{10}^{(0)}m_{01}^{(1)})\underbrace{ \frac{m_{00}^{(1)}}{m_{00}^{(0)2}}}_{j=1,i=1}\\
    &\quad
    + m_{10}^{(0)}m_{01}^{(0)}
    \left(
      \underbrace{\frac{m_{00}^{(2)}}{{m_{00}^{(0)2}}}}_{j=1,i=2}
      - \underbrace{\frac{m_{00}^{(1)2}}{m_{00}^{(0)2}}}_{j=2,i=1}
    \right)\\
    &= m_{11}^{(2)} \\
    &\quad-
    \frac{
      m_{10}^{(1)}m_{01}^{(1)}
    + m_{10}^{(0)}m_{01}^{(2)}
    + m_{10}^{(2)}m_{01}^{(0)}
    + m_{10}^{(0)}m_{01}^{(0)}m_{00}^{(1)2}
    }{m_{00}^{(0)}}\\
    &\quad
    + \frac{m_{00}^{(1)}(m_{10}^{(1)}m_{01}^{(0)} + m_{10}^{(0)}m_{01}^{(1)} - m_{10}^{(0)}m_{01}^{(0)}m_{00}^{(1)})}{m_{00}^{(0)2}}  \\
    &\quad
    + \frac{m_{00}^{(2)}m_{10}^{(0)}m_{01}^{(0)}}{m_{00}^{(0)2}}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Why should I not be allowed to match $*^{(0)}$ and $*^{(2)}$. Sure, they are on different scales, but I suppose they can be combined, anyway. Do I miss something, or is there additional modelling work to be done to get rid of those terms?
For reference, this is equation (G.29) and following in the paper. I could just accept to not mix them, but I would like to understand whats happening here.

Thanks

ps: I am not allowed to create new tags, and the ones I found do not match the problem, sorry about that

Comment: The general solution comes from expanding the denominator using geometric series, e.g. $1/(1+a_1x+a_2x^2)\approx 1-a_1x+(a_1^2-a_2)x^2$.

Comment: I forget about this every time, thanks for pointing that out. I worked out the geometric series, but this gives me even more terms to deal with. I will edit the question in a minute to incorporate the new finding. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed the tags. There are a couple of mistakes. It should be $(m_{00}^{(1)})^2$ in two places instead of $(m_{00}^{(2)})^2$. You also forgot the denominator towards the end.

Comment: Anyway, your calculation is essentially correct (in particular, different orders may get mixed as long as the total order is correct). If it doesn't match the paper, then the paper must have some assumptions you are missing. For example, maybe $m_{00}$ is independent of $\epsilon$, or $m_{10}^{(0)}=m_{01}^{(0)}=0$, something like that.

Comment: Thanks! You're totally right about the $m_{00}^{(1)2}$ stuff, I even wrote the right thing in the underbraces. :)

Comment: Wrote too long on the edit, rest of the stuff below: :O

The denominator should be squared not ruled out, yes. Don't know why I did this. 

Thanks, I will check back with my advisor on the assumptions. As this is for fluid simulation, $m_{00}=\rho$ and $m_{10}=\rho v_x$, so I don't see anything which could be done there (I don't want to assume incompressibility). As this is the appendix of the paper, the authors excluded many assumptions and calculations.

Anyways, you helped me to great extend, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mailed the author about it, and got a super fast response:

The key is, that I can choose my frame of reference once in the analysis, and to simplify the calculations, one chooses it in this case such that $m_{10}=0=m_{01}$.

Much more easy than I thought.